# Can't add force to player with another object in Unity 2D with C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm just starting with Unity, and I want the player to be able to create a small explosion that launches them after detonating with C#. I've already gotten the object to spawn, but the force isn't being added for some reason. I've made sure that the Rigidbody is correct, but the player is still not moved after it detonates. Here's the code:

```
    using UnityEngine;

public class plosionSelfScript : MonoBehaviour {
    // Start is called before the first frame update
   public GameObject player;
   private Rigidbody2D playerRB;
   private int wait;

   void Start() {
    playerRB = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    Debug.Log(playerRB);
    wait = 0;

   }

   void Update() {
    wait = wait + 1;
    if (wait >= 20) {
        playerRB.AddForce(new Vector2(5000, 5000));
        Destroy(gameObject);

    }

   }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Could I first suggest you start by making a few small modifications to your code:

```
public class plosionSelfScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    private Rigidbody2D playerRB;   // Why not store this in the first place?
    public float waitTime;
    private float timer;

    void Start ( )
    {
        playerRB = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ( );
        Debug.Log ( playerRB );
        timer = 0;
    }

    void Update ( )
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if ( timer >= waitTime )
        {
            playerRB.AddForce ( new Vector2 ( 5000, 5000 ) );
            Debug.Log ( "Added force and destroying object." );
            Destroy ( gameObject );
        }
    }
}
```

In your previous code, you waited for a value of '20'. Given that most devices will call the Update method around about 60 times per seconds, your explosions would happen 1/3 of a second after it was created. I don't think that's what you wanted.

Given that though, it's still not clear why the force wasn't applied. You would have to check a few additional things as well:

- is your RigidBody2D marked as kinematic?
- is your RigidBody2D extremely heaving, or is there other forces acting on it?
- is your player script overriding the RigidBody2D physics in any way?

Comment: Thanks for the help, there is another script that is a component of the player that may be overriding this code, but I don't know how to tell. I don't think it is, as I've tried adding the same force to the player's script directly, and it worked perfectly, but it's not working for this script.